# How to append a slug to the end of the url in Laravel 5.3 using eloquent-sluggable package?

Tags: laravel, http, nginx, slug

I have slug eloquent package. I want to create a url like this:
http://www.example.com/houses/id/house-with-2-bedrooms
Let me explain the url:

houses and id represents the resource  and id as stated by the rest archicture.

the house-with-2-bedrooms segment is the slug itself.
the portion that is dynamic is the number 2, representing the number of bedrooms that a house has.
So I could have

```
http://www.example.com/houses/100/house-with-2-bedrooms
http://www.example.com/houses/101/house-with-2-bedrooms
http://www.example.com/houses/102/house-with-3-bedrooms
```

I know that slug is more often used to create more complex urls, removing url unwanted characters like ~ and ^ but I only want a simple one for now.

I read the tutorial on the Git web site and couldn't make it work neither  understand I was doing.

So far I have this:

My House model has a slug field.

I defined the Sluggable trait:

My model:

```
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;

class House extends Model
{
    use Sluggable; 

       public function announcement()
        {           
             return $this->belongsTo(\App\Announcement::class, 'id' , 'id');  
        }   

   protected $table = 'house';
   protected $primaryKey = 'id';
   protected $fillable = array( 'id', 'capacity', 'bedrooms', 'pool', 'price', 'dir_id', 'identifier', 'photos', 'views', 'active', 'description', 'slug');
   public $timestamps = false;

   protected $connection = 'eloquent_db';

         public function sluggable()
          {
             return ['slug' => ['source' => 'bedrooms'] ];
          }


 }
```

My controller:

```
route::resource('houses', HousesController').
```

Comment: post your routes too

Comment: I will update my question with the route. There's nothing special about my route It's just route::resource('houses', HousesController'). I was expecting the need to define a route to support slugs but the tutorial didn't teach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve that

On route

```
Route::resource('houses', 'HousesController', ['except' => 'show']);
Route::get('/houses/{id}/{slug}', 'HousesController@show')->name('houses.show');
```

On view for generating URL

```
<a href="{{ route('houses.show', [$house->id, $house->slug]) }}">Sample House</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function in your model as slug that you want to display for example Myslug like this:

```
class House extends Eloquent
{
    use Sluggable;

public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'myslug'
        ]
    ];
}

public function getMyslugAttribute() {
    return 'house-with-' . $this->bedrooms.'-bedrooms;
}
}
```

or whatever you want

then store it in your database and call it from table everywhere that you want like this:

```
$house->slug;
```

you can define a url however you want

```
<a href="{{ url('houses/'.$house->id.'/'.$house->slug)}}">house link</a>
```